# Python - How to split string by non-alphanumberical, but keep any non-alphanumerical aswell

Tags: python, list

string = "Tes.t / &hi-&"

Expected Output - ["Tes" , "." , "t" , " " ," /" , "&" , "hi" ,"-", "&"]

or

Expected Output - ["Tes" , "." , "t" , " / &" , "hi" , "-&"]

Preferably the latter output would be more better but either would work perfectly.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something where you check if a character is in `ascii_letters` or not and add it to the same string or a different to the last depending on this. This could look like;

```
from string import ascii_letters
import sys
from typing import List

def main(input_string: str) -> List[str]:

    output = []
    sub_string = ''
    last_was_ascii = None

    for char in input_string:
        char_is_ascii = char in ascii_letters
        if last_was_ascii is None or char_is_ascii == last_was_ascii:
            sub_string += char
        else:
            output.append(sub_string)
            sub_string = char
        last_was_ascii = char_is_ascii
    output.append(sub_string)

    print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Which given the command line input `python example_file.py "Tes.t / &hi-&"` will print `['Tes', '.', 't', ' / &', 'hi', '-&']`, i.e. the second example you have listed.

It's a little verbose however does the trick

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def splitnonalpha(s):
    """Split whenever the type of following characater is different (i.e. alpha or non-alpha)"""

    current = s[0]
    result = []
    for pos in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[pos].isalpha() and current[-1].isalpha():
            current += s[pos]  # same type as previous
        elif not s[pos].isalpha() and not current[-1].isalpha():
            current += s[pos]   # same type as previous
        else:
            # Different type-->store current, and reset to current character
            result.append(current)
            current = s[pos]

    if current:
        result.append(current)

    return result
```

**Test**

```
s = "Tes.t / &hi-&"
print(splitnonalpha(s))
```

**Output**

```
['Tes', '.', 't', ' / &', 'hi', '-&']
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use regex:

1. find all alphanumerical:

   ```
   an = re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", s)
   ```
2. find all non alphanumerical:

   ```
   non_an = re.findall("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", s)
   ```
3. zip them:

   ```
   ziped = zip(an, non_an)
   ```
4. flatten the zip:

   ```
   flat = sum(ziped, ())
   ```

or in a one liner:

```
sum(zip(re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", s), re.findall("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", s)), ())
```

to cover cases that include more alphanumerical than non alphanumerical (or vice versa) use itertools.zip_longest() and drop nulls:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
[x for x in sum(zip_longest(re.findall("\w+", s), re.findall("[\W]+", s)), ()) if x]
```

Comment: Why not replacing ***a-zA-Z0-9*** with just ***\w***?

Comment: Okay :)  You can replace ***[a-zA-Z0-9]+*** with ***\w+*** and ***[^a-zA-Z0-9]+*** with ***[\W]+***